# MetaTrader and Python integration using nquotes

Tags: python-3.x, ironpython, metatrader4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2iTE.png) - I have a completed installation of meta trader 4 and nquotes but I can 't  run any python file

- I follow this tutorial: http://www.nquotes.net/docs/metatrader-with-python/ and also downloaded
  IronPython but it gives the below error :
  Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
  Exception thrown: 'System. Exception' in PyMovingAverage.dll

Answer (score 0):

please try this solution:

Its a great solution for python and metatrader:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

import io

TZ_SERVER = 'Europe/Tallinn' # EET
TZ_LOCAL  = 'Europe/Budapest'
TZ_UTC    = 'UTC'

class Pytrader_API:             
  
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket_error: int = 0
        self.socket_error_message: str = ''
        self.order_return_message: str = ''
        self.order_error: int = 0
        self.connected: bool = False
        self.timeout: bool = False
        self.command_OK: bool = False
        self.command_return_error: str = ''
        self.debug: bool = False
        self.version: str = '1.06'
        self.max_bars: int = 5000
        self.max_ticks: int = 5000
        self.timeout_value: int = 60
        self.instrument_conversion_list: dict = {}
        self.instrument_name_broker: str = ''
        self.instrument_name_universal: str = ''
        self.date_from: datetime = '2000/01/01, 00:00:00'
        self.date_to: datetime = datetime.now()
        self.instrument: str = ''

    def Set_timeout(self,
                    timeout_in_seconds: int = 60
                    ):
        """
        Set time out value for socket communication with MT4 or MT5 EA/Bot.
        Args:
            timeout_in_seconds: the time out value
        Returns:
            None
        """
        self.timeout_value = timeout_in_seconds
        self.sock.settimeout(self.timeout_value)
        self.sock.setblocking(1)
        return

    def Disconnect(self):
        """
        Closes the socket connection to a MT4 or MT5 EA bot.
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            bool: True or False
        """

        self.sock.close()
        return True

    def Connect(self,
                server: str = '',
                port: int = 2345,
                instrument_lookup: dict = []) -> bool:
        """
        Connects to a MT4 or MT5 EA/Bot.
        Args:
            server: Server IP address, like -> '127.0.0.1', '192.168.5.1'
            port: port number
            instrument_lookup: dictionairy with general instrument names and broker intrument names
        Returns:
            bool: True or False
        """
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setblocking(1)
        self.port = port
        self.server = server
        self.instrument_conversion_list = instrument_lookup

        if (len(self.instrument_conversion_list) == 0):
            print('Broker Instrument list not available or empty')
            self.socket_error_message = 'Broker Instrument list not available'
            return False

        try:
            self.sock.connect((self.server, self.port))
            try:
                data_received = self.sock.recv(1000000)
                self.connected = True
                self.socket_error = 0
                self.socket_error_message = ''
                return True
            except socket.error as msg:
                self.socket_error = 100
                self.socket_error_message = 'Could not connect to server.'
                self.connected = False
                return False
        except socket.error as msg:
            print(
                "Couldnt connect with the socket-server: %self.sock\n terminating program" %
                msg)
            self.connected = False
            self.socket_error = 101
            self.socket_error_message = 'Could not connect to server.'
            return False

    def Check_connection(self) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if connection with MT terminal/Ea bot is still active.
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            bool: True or False
        """

        self.command = 'F000#0#'
        self.command_return_error = ''
        ok, dataString = self.send_command(self.command)

        try:
            if (ok == False):
                self.command_OK = False
                return False

            x = dataString.split('#')

            if x[1] == 'OK':
                self.timeout = True
                self.command_OK = True
                return True
            else:
                self.timeout = False
                self.command_OK = True
                return False
        except:
            self.command_return_error = 'Unexpected socket communication error'
            self.command_OK = False
            return False

    @property
    def IsConnected(self) -> bool:
        """Returns connection status.
        Returns:
            bool: True or False
        """
        return self.connected

    def Get_static_account_info(self) -> dict:
        """
        Retrieves static account information.
        Returns: Dictionary with:
            Account name,
            Account number,
            Account currency,
            Account type,
            Account leverage,
            Account trading allowed,
            Account maximum number of pending orders,
            Account margin call percentage,
            Account close open trades margin percentage
        """
        self.command_return_error = ''

        ok, dataString = self.send_command('F001#0#')
        if (ok == False):
            self.command_OK = False
            return None

        if self.debug:
            print(dataString)

        x = dataString.split('#')
        if x[0] != 'F001':
            self.command_return_error = str(x[2])
            self.command_OK = False
            return None

        returnDict = {}
        del x[0:2]
        x.pop(-1)

        returnDict['name'] = str(x[0])
        returnDict['login'] = str(x[1])
        returnDict['currency'] = str(x[2])
        returnDict['type'] = str(x[3])
        returnDict['leverage'] = int(x[4])
        returnDict['trade_allowed'] = bool(x[5])
        returnDict['limit_orders'] = int(x[6])
        returnDict['margin_call'] = float(x[7])
        returnDict['margin_close'] = float(x[8])

        self.command_OK = True
        return returnDict

    def Get_dynamic_account_info(self) -> dict:
        """
        Retrieves dynamic account information.
        Returns: Dictionary with:
            Account balance,
            Account equity,
            Account profit,
            Account margin,
            Account margin level,
            Account margin free
        """
        self.command_return_error = ''

        ok, dataString = self.send_command('F002#0#')
        if (ok == False):
            self.command_OK = False
            return None

        if self.debug:
            print(dataString)

        x = dataString.split('#')
        if x[0] != 'F002':
            self.command_return_error = str(x[2])
            self.command_OK = False
            return None

        returnDict = {}
        del x[0:2]
        x.pop(-1)

        returnDict['balance'] = float(x[0])
        returnDict['equity'] = float(x[1])
        returnDict['profit'] = float(x[2])
        returnDict['margin'] = float(x[3])
        returnDict['margin_level'] = float(x[4])
        returnDict['margin_free'] = float(x[5])

        self.command_OK = True
        return returnDict

    def Get_PnL(self,
                    date_from: datetime = datetime(2021, 3, 1, tzinfo = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")),
                    date_to: datetime = datetime.now()) -> pd.DataFrame:
        '''    
        Retrieves profit loss info.
        Args:
            date_from: start date
            date_to: end date
        Returns: Dictionary with:
            realized_profit             profit of all closed positions
            unrealized_profit           profit of all open positions
            buy_profit                  profit of closed buy positions
            sell_profit                 profit of closed sell positions
            positions_in_profit         number of profit positions
            positions in loss           number of loss positions
            volume_in_profit            total volume of positions in profit
            volume_in_loss              total volume of positions in loss
        
        total_profit = 0.0
        buy_profit = 0.0
        sell_profit = 0.0
        trades_in_loss = 0
        trades_in_profit = 0
        volume_in_loss = 0.0
        volume_in_profit = 0.0
        commission_in_loss = 0.0
        commission_in_profit = 0.0
        swap_in_loss = 0.0
        swap_in_profit = 0.0
        unrealized_profit = 0.0
```

this example taken from [Python with Metatrader](https://github.com/TheSnowGuru/PyTrader-python-mt4-mt5-trading-api-connector-drag-n-drop) API